# How do I simply take an attribute from an array and put it into another? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, variables, push

I bet it's a super simple answer.

Say I have an array of attributes:

```
  var array = ['green','blue','red','purple','orange','yellow','magenta'];
```

How would I take values in this array and transfer them into 3 different groups? 
So it would look like

```
  firstGroup = green, blue, red
  secondGroup = purple, orange
  thirdGroup = yellow, magenta
```

Could I simply create some sort of for loop that uses the .push function? Or does the .push function not work that way?

Comment: What is the criteria of split, which element goes into which group?

Comment: Well, ideally I'd want one group to have no more than one more than 1 element than the other groups. So 

         firstGroup = green, blue, red
  secondGroup = purple, orange
  thirdGroup = yellow, magenta

just the first 3 elements into the first group, then the next 2 into the second, and the last 2 into the third.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var array = ['green','blue','red','purple','orange','yellow','magenta'];
var firstGroup = array.slice(0,3);
var secondGroup = array.slice(3,5);
var thirdGroup = array.slice(5,7);
```

**Edit**

I guess you could do something like this since you don't want to use `slice`:

```
var array = ['green','blue','red','purple','orange','yellow','magenta'];
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    var index = i % 3;
    result[index] = result[index] || [];
    result[index].push(array[i]);    
}
```

The order of the items is not exactly the same as in your question.  Does that matter to your solution?

Comment: The solution isn't using `splice`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant slice.

Comment: I guess you could do something similar with `splice`.  Is there a reason why you don't want to use `slice`? Do you want to use a loop?

Comment: How would you do it with a loop?

Comment: Is there a way that you could use a function in which you would input an array and how many groups you want and then return the array split up into groups?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array is OK as well. You can use "slice" method.

```
var newArray = [array.slice(0, 3), array.slice(3, 5), array.slice(5, 7)];
```